# What is the difference between "*x = 1" and "x = 1" in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm very new to C. I come from a Java background, and I'm having a hard time understanding pointers. My understanding of what `*x = 1` is take the memory address of x and assign it to 1, where as `x = 1` means assign the variable x to the value 1.

Am I correct?

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*x = 1;
```

means that x contains a memory address, assign 1 to that memory address.

```
x = 1;
```

means assign 1 to the variable x.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as written you have it completely backwards, since you're saying assign x to the value 1 etc.

x=1 means store the value 1 to the variable x.

*x=1 means store the value 1 at the memory address x points to.

Answer (score 0):

x  = VARIABLE

*x = POINTER TO ADDRESS

Answer (score 0):

By saying `x=1` means you are directly assigning the value *1* into the *x*. Where as `*x=1` has a bit different approach.

Say, `int y = 10` and *x* is a pointer which is **pointing to the address of y** by defining `int *x = &y`. After declaration of `*x`, through out the program, `*x` will be treated as **the value at the address of y**. So, when `*x=1` is used, the the value at the address of *y*, which was 10 earlier, will be changed to *1* now. Thus, `y=1` and `*x=1` are internally doing same thing.

You can follow [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) for detailed understanding in simpler way about C pointers.